# Need to exlude 2nd column in creating a percent of total and running sum measure

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Hi My data looks like the screenshot attached. Need to exclude the second column 'not....' from the percentage of total calculations such that the calculations start from Day 0 and computed over the grand totals [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the values from the calculations and recalculate the percentages with only the remaining "Day N" columns then right-click on the "Not..." column and select **Exclude**.

If you simply don't want to see the column and want the current calculations to remain then right-click on the "Not..." column and select **Hide**. To unhide the column later you can select **Reveal Hidden Data** from the **Analysis** menu.

Comment: Thank you Keshia. I was able to figure this out. Can you please also guide, whenever i use the running sum on the rows, it does not make a pyramid and the values reach a 100%. In this chart i've minimized that by using the values filter to remove such values. But what would be the appropriate way to go about this?

Comment: Hmm, Tableau doesn't generally add data where data doesn't exist, so if you are seeing all the rows completely filled in it usually means there is data there, even if it is 0. In this case, adding a filter on something like SUM(value) where it must be above 0 would be an appropriate method to remove that extra data and only get the pyramid. 